# Setting has_many through double belong_to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have tables like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars, through: :user_cars
end

class UserCar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :car

  validates_uniqueness_of :car, scope: :user
end


class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_car, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :user, through: :user_cars
end
```

Every user can have a car, and car can belong to just one user.

I want to be able to retrieve all the cars that belong to the user, but `user.cars` doesn't work.

What I am missing? Are the relations correctly set?

Comment: Do you really need `UserCar`?

Comment: I want to keep it so I could eventually extend it that one car can belong to multiple users

Answer (score 0):

The error was in fact a `typo` issue.

```
has_one :user, through: :user_cars
```

Should have been:

```
has_one :user, through: :user_car
```

Without `s` at the end of `through` association

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `though` association without first having a regular association. So your `User` model needs to look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_cars
  has_many :cars, through: :user_cars
end
```

This is because when you say `through: :somethings` ActiveRecord is looking for an existing association called `somethings` to pass through. When you specify `through`, you're giving it the name of an association, not the name of a model or table.

To prove this, you could change the assocation name of `user_cars` to be `belongings`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :belongings, class_name: 'UserCar'
  has_many :cars, through: :belongings
end
```

Our associated model (UserCar) and table name (user_cars) didn't change, but since we changed the name of the association, we have to change the name of the `through` value to match.

I know I'm late to the party, but I thought it would be helpful for anyone else who comes along.